# ¿Cómo programar el envío de archivos adjuntos por Outlook a una hora del día?

Tags: vb.net

Esa es la cuestión, necesito que un archivo "x" se envíe por correo a una hora "y" lo que tengo es esto, pero es solo para enviar texto plano:

```
Sub Item_PropertyChange(ByVal Name)
   Select Case Name
   Case “Status”
           if Item.Status = 2 then ‘2 = Completed
                   Set NewItem = Application.CreateItem(0)
                   NewItem.To = “correo@direccion.com”
                   NewItem.Recipients.ResolveAll
                   NewItem.Subject = “ASUNTO”
                   NewItem.Body = “Cuerpo mensaje.”
                   NewItem.Display
           End IF
   End Select
   End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Aparte de las ideas de crear un servicio de windows

[Introducción a las aplicaciones de servicios de Windows](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/d56de412(VS.80).aspx)

debes poder planificar la tarea para que aplique el `scheduler` con una librería como ser

[Task Scheduler Engine](https://taskschedulerengine.codeplex.com/)

de esta forma no tiene que usar un `timer`

---

Otra alternativa sería usando el `Windows Task Scheduler`

[Task Scheduler Managed Wrapper](http://taskscheduler.codeplex.com/)

Con este podrías definir tareas directo en windows

Answer (score 0):

Para que este corriendo el programa puedes:

1. Tener un servicio de windows  o
2. Tener un programa corriendo en el system tray (son las aplicaciones que estan corriendo junto al reloj del sistema)

Para programar un servicio de windows te puedes basar en [este](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/zt39148a(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2) tutorial

Para crear una aplicación en el [system tray](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/75822/Create-a-System-Tray-Application-in-VB-NET)

O mejor aún, [combinarlos](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/23176/Create-a-system-tray-icon-and-a-dialog-for-a-Windo)

Finalmente para enviar correos con archivos adjuntos te puedes basar en este [código](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1962518/142904)

En esta parte es donde se esta adjuntando el archivo

```
If FileExists(AttachmentFile) Then _
             .Attachments.Add(AttachmentFile)
```

En el código no viene la parte de las credenciales para el sevidor SMTP, pero básicamente es:

```
SMTP_Client_instance = New System.Net.NetworkCredential(usuario, password)
```